# ¿Cómo crear una tabla utilizando parámetros de stored procedures en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Estoy intentando crear una lista de tablas cuyos nombres estarán precedidos por el nombre del usuario. Para ello he creado un `stored procedure` con el siguiente código.

---

### STORED PROCEDURE

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CrearDatosUsuario]
@UserName varchar(50)
AS
GO
/**/----    *TABLAS*    ----/**/
----|   CREATE TABLE UserName.Tareas    |----
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[@UserName + Tareas](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Titulo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Tiempo] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO    
----|   CREATE TABLE UserName.Estados   |----
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[@UserName + Estados](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Valor] [float] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
----|   CREATE TABLE UserName.TareasEstados |----
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[@UserName + TareasEstados](
    [IDTareas] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDEstados] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
----|   CREATE TABLE UserName.Descripciones |----
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[@UserName + Descripciones](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Descripcion] [varchar](500) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

El `stored procedure` se ejecuta sin errores pero cuando reviso la base de datos las tablas no tienen el nombre de usuario.

---

### Resultado Esperado:

- **Tablas**

  - dbo.JuanTareas
  - dbo.JuanEstados
  - dbo.JuanTareasEstados
  - dbo.JuanDescripciones

### Resultado Obtenido:

- **Tablas**

  - dbo.@UserName + Tareas
  - dbo.@UserName + Estados
  - dbo.@UserName + TareasEstados
  - dbo.@UserName + Descripciones

Comment: Hola.. ni mire el SP... pero de por si suena a mala idea.. porque querrias crear nombres de tablas asi????

Comment: No es buen diseño repetir la estructura de tablas varias veces para separar los datos de varios usuarios. Lo correcto es tener una sola tabla con una columna `UsuarioId` o algo por el estilo para poder identificar a quién pertenecen los datos. Con este modelo, ¿cómo vas a hacer cuando te toque poner al día algún dato para todos los usuarios?

Comment: Mi intención inicial era crear una base de datos local por cada usuario, lamentablemente c# no me permite crear base de datos de forma dinámica
 asi que decidi usar una estructura de tablas dinámicas por usuario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es que no es válido hacerlo de la forma que lo haces, lamentablemente debes caer en una sentencia SQL dinámica. Supongamos que quieres crear una tabla `JuanTareas`, lo que debes hacer es construir la sentencia de creación en una variable y ejecutarla luego, veamos:

```
DECLARE @SQL        NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @UserName   VARCHAR(50)

SELECT  @UserName   = 'Juan'

SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[' + @UserName + 'Tareas](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Titulo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Tiempo] [int] NOT NULL
)'

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE name = 'JuanTareas'
```

En `@SQL` tenemos nuestra consulta de creación, que ejecutaremos mediante [`sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). El `select` final es simplemente para verificar que la tabla está correctamente creada.